# Should I write the code for OnPropertyChanged and BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't get it. I've been following some tutorials and reading some articles online and sometimes OnPropertyChanged is used without even writing the code for it.

```
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
```

and as for BooleanToVisibilityConverter, I find users creating it like this:

```
 public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

but when I'm writing `Converter={StaticResource ....}` BooleanToVisibilityConverter shows up without even having the code above. So my question is, are these functions somewhere in a library or you have to write them yourself.

Comment: With a recent C# version you could write `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));` without previously checking for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you show is using `Hidden` if `false`. The built-in converter is `Collapsed` if `false`.

This is my opinion, but I think many create their own because it affords them the ability to add in extra functionality. Myself, I have always created my own and used the `parameter` so that I may control what comes back if `false`.

---

I don't quite follow your PropertyChanged question.

If `PropertyChanged` is null, then your `handler` will be null and it won't execute. You don't need to write any other code. WPF behind the scenes hooks into it. You don't have to do anything other than call it to signal you've updated the property. WPF knew to hook into it because it saw `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your object.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: My second question about PropertyChanged is whether there is an existent function (like BooleanToVisibilityConverter) or we should write it on our own (like the first code I posted).

Comment: You write it yourself. Usually in a base class your objects use.

Comment: Thank you, you answered everything in details.